# Apache proxy change HTTP verb

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I am running an Apache front with a few microservices behind, one of which exposes an RPC API that requires that requests be made with `POST` where client applications would traditionally use `GET`. Namely, how can I use Apache (or anything else) to proxy and transform a `GET` request with a parameter, eg.

```
GET  https://wherever.com/parcel/4809284          // <== id
```

into

```
POST http://microservice/rpc/parcel/
```

with a JSON payload as `{ "id": "4809284" }` ?

Comment: You could find a developer to write some code to do this. It's unlikely you'll find anything off the shelf.

Comment: Alas, I feared it wouldn't be a common scenario. The service I'm trying to proxy to is Postgrest, a fine piece of code but its RPC in `POST` is a little awkward I find.